# $ \sum_{x=1}^n {{n-1} \choose {x-1}} {N \choose x} = {{N+n-1}\choose n}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, factorial

I am working on a random variable problem. To prove a PMF to be a valid one, I need to establish the following identity :

$ \sum_{x=1}^n {{n-1} \choose {x-1}} {N \choose x}  = {{N+n-1}\choose n}$

I tried proving it by induction and using factorials, but was unable to solve. Somebody please suggest how to proceed.

P.S.: According to my calculations for the random variable problem, this identity must hold. However I may be wrong and it may be the case that the identity is invalid. If so, please mention.

Comment: This isn't an inequality, it's a summation.

Comment: @Prometheus Thanks for pointing out. I've corrected the statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that
$$\binom{n-1}{x-1}=\binom{n-1}{n-x}$$
by symmetry. Hence, you wish to solve
$$\sum_{x=1}^n\binom{n-1}{n-x}\binom Nx=\binom{N+n-1}{n}.$$

This is known as *Vandermonde's identity*. You will find many solutions on this site.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know about Vandermonde's identity. Thank you. @Zuy